# implement infinite scroller in angular2

Tags: angular, typescript

I would like to implement infinite scrolling for an *ng-for of DIVs in angular2 component. For this I need to somehow hook to the window onScroll event via angular method. Then in angular I will be able to load more items into the data items array when user has scrolled pass some point of the page.

Anyone has ideas how to hook to the window.scroll event from angular (inside ng2 component)?

Comment: `(scroll)="update($event)"` on the element in your template you want to get scroll notifications should do what you want, no?

Comment: Tried the following, but doesn't work

<div style="height: 100%" (scroll)="onScroll($ev);">
    <div *ng-for="#row of rows"></div>
</div>

the onScroll(ev) function wont get called at all on component.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Use `(target:event)="handler()"` notation for listening to global events. You can use `window`, `document` or `body` as a target. For your case it will be `(window:scroll)="onScroll($event)"`. See [this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/LngREiDpRJEQJpwj7Dmd).

```ts
import {Component} from 'angular2/core'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div (window:scroll)="onScroll($event)">
      <h1>Hello Angular2</h1>
      ...
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {

  onScroll(event) {
    console.log('scroll event', event);
  }
}
```

Comment: This does work but how do you get the amount you've scrolled.  event.scrollY == 57 kinda thing?

Comment: @LukeDupin try `window.scrollY`. That's what worked for me.

Comment: Not working in my case. I am applying this to a div inside my application which is built in ng2-material design. Problem is (window:scroll) doesnot fire in my case @alexpods

Comment: im new in angular, and i don't understand, anybody can help me to implement this?

Answer (score 11):

You can use @HostListener to detect Scrolling. This is how I have done this

```
 export class AppComponent {

  @HostListener('window:scroll', ['$event'])
    onScroll($event: Event): void {
    console.log("On Scroll");
    //Logic To Check whether we are bottom of the page
    if ((window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) >= document.body.offsetHeight) {
      console.log("On Scroll Down");
      //Write logic here for loading new content.
    }
  }

}
```

Hope this will help you :)

Answer (score 1):

component.html

```
<div (scroll)="onScroll($event)">
    //Content
</div>
```

Now i just used the $event.target properties `scrollTopMax` and `scrollTop`:

component.ts

```
onScroll(event: any): void {
   let elementHeight = event.target.scrollTopMax;
   let scrollPosition = event.target.scrollTop;
   if( elementHeight - scrollPosition < 100) {
       //add Content
   }
}
```

Of course you will need some function checking if new content is already rendered. 
If not the `onScroll()` function will be called much too often.

In my case i insert other component with  `*ngFor` and created and `@Output` to notify the parent about a finished rendering.

child.component.ts

```
@Output()
rendered = new EventEmitter();

ngAfterViewChecked() {
    this.rendered.emit(<uniqueIdentifier>);
}
```

component.html

```
<div (scroll)="onScroll($event)">
    <child *ngFor="element in displayedElement"
        (rendered)="elementRendered($event)">
    </child>
```

component.ts

```
elements: any;
displayedElements: any[];
renderedElements: new Set();

addElements(): void {
    /////
}

elementRendered(<uniqueIdentifier>: any) {
    this.renderedElements.add(<uniqueIdentifier>);
}

onScroll(event: any): void {
    if( this.displayedElements.length == this.renderedElements.size) {
        let elementHeight = event.target.scrollTopMax;
        let scrollPosition = event.target.scrollTop;
        if( elementHeight - scrollPosition < 100) {
            this.addElements();
        }
    }
}
```