# Using trackBy with infinite scrolling in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5

I have a service that returns all of my data on the client side.
And now I have a table that lists all of the data:

```
<tr *ngFor="let row of allData">
```

What I want to do is combine trackBy (so that the DOM doesn't get rendered on every change) and scrolling.
So say the table displays 30 rows the first time, when the user gets scrolls to the bottom, the next 30 should be added (but using the same created elements), so I have view recycling.

How do I achieve this in angular 5?

Comment: calculate scrollHeight- (scrollTop OR scrollBottom) of your main div where you wants to apply scroll and based on value call for next records and append it in your existing datasource

Comment: you can refer how infinite scroll build, hope it will help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34496508/implement-infinite-scroller-in-angular2  http://rintoj.github.io/angular2-virtual-scroll/

Answer (score 0):

Rendering views are an expensive task, and as we are typically rolling the viewport on scrolls which involves removing and adding with the same number of views. rather than deleting the views and creating them all again, *we recycle them(In android it's called recycler view)* So we detach the views, remove the context, and cache them so we can attach them and re-context them on the add cycle. Therefore saving a considerable number of script/render cycles.

here is an angular library that does that for us in a better way, better than trackBy function

https://rintoj.github.io/ngx-virtual-scroller/about